# How to uncheck a single radio button if disabled by another radio?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

jQuery newbie, here. I can't get this to work. This is what I'm using to disable a radio button based on a previous radio button.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('input[name="a"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '1') {
            $('input[name="b"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('input[name="b"][value="1"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

and:

```
<input type="radio" name="a" value="1" /> A-1
<input type="radio" name="a" value="2" /> A-2

<input type="radio" name="b" value="1" /> B-1
<input type="radio" name="b" value="2" /> B-2
```

So if I checked A-2, B-1 gets disabled. But say I had B-1 checked to begin with, and then I checked A-2, then I'd want B-1 to get unchecked. I've tried adding this in:

```
if($('input[name="b"][value="1"]').is(':disabled')) {
    $('input[name="b"][value="1"]').removeAttr('checked');
}
```

It does the job, but it also unchecks B-2 if I had that checked first. I only want B-1 to get unchecked. (I hope this makes sense.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You always want the previously-checked radio button to become deselected, if another radio is selected?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="a"]').change(function () {
    var $b = $('input[name="b"]');
    if (this.value == 1) {
        $b.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('input[name="b"][value="1"]:checked').removeAttr('checked');  // the selector behavior is funky here...
        $b.attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

this works as you want.

there is an issue with the [value="1"] selector thou (when used without :checked), smells like a jquery bug. But don't worry about it ;)

and [a little fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/zW5rS/) ^^

Answer (score 0):

I had to learn something like that in a hurry in the past: the trick is make a family of radio buttons:

```
family NAME
  child ID0
  child ID1
  child IDn
```

In you specific case, you might be looking for something like this (gender):

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id='male' value="M" > Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id='female' value"F" > Female
```

And, for instance, likes:

```
<input type="radio" name="likes" id='tv' value="TV" > Watchs TV
<input type="radio" name="likes" id='radio' value="radio" > Listens to Radio
```

When you have a FAMILY of radio buttons, once one is clicked, the other is unclicked automatically.

Then you can check either by just

```
$('#male').is(':checked') .... $('#female').is(':checked') .....
```

And, you can, also, start any of them disabled or not or disable the other by clicking this: $('#male').click();